# Store same length content to one variable in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a file with some rows with content as below :

```
1.000000 - 1.000200 0 -> 2 A-MPDU 1.000000 - 1.000100 SUCCESS 1.000100 - 1.000200 FAIL
1.000425 1 TIMEOUT
1.000150 - 1.000350 1 -> 3 A-MPDU 1.000150 - 1.000250 FAIL 1.000250 - 1.000350 FAIL
```

Then I want combine row1 and row3 to one variable after splitting to different element :

```
for z = 1:length(myTextArray)
   temp = regexp(A{z,1}, ' ', 'split');
   if cols == 15
     C1 = temp;
   end
end
```

But C1 only stores the latest "temp". How to make C1 stores row1 and row3 value (of course in different row as well)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
    ix = 0;
    C1 = {};

    for z = 1:length(myTextArray)
            temp = regexp(A{z,1}, ' ', 'split');

            if numel(temp) == 15
                    ix = ix + 1;
                    C1{ix} = temp;
            end;
    end;
```

Basically you create a new index `ix` in the cell array `C1`.

**Later edit**

This will create a 2D cell array rather than a 1D cell array of 1D cell arrays:

```
    ix = 0;
    C1 = cell(0,15);

    for z = 1:length(myTextArray)
            temp = regexp(A{z,1}, ' ', 'split');
            if numel(temp) == 15
                    ix = ix + 1;
                    C1(ix, :) = temp;
            end;
    end;
```

which is, basically, the same answer EJG89 gave earlier, with the difference that it will not contain empty cell rows.

Comment: However it will show <15x1 cell> twice in variable editor and I must click again so it will make C1{1,1} and C2{1,2}. What I want is when I click C1, it will show directly 2 rows with those values? How to do that?

Comment: @user2290560 you're incorrectly indexing into the cell array. C1 now is a vector cell array of row cell arrays, not a matrix cell array, so you need to index it like `C1{1}{3}` instead of `C1{1,3}`. If you want the matriceal cell array, I'll add the code to the answer, which is pretty straightforward, by the way...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new row. Since you are absolutely sure they are the same length you can stick with a matrix format.

First prelocate space, number of rows m, times number of columns, n:

```
z = ;
n = ;

C1 = zeros(m,n) % You might need a cell instead of an array

for z = 1:length(myTextArray)
   temp = regexp(A{z,1}, ' ', 'split');
   if cols == 15
     C1(z,:) = temp; % Important change right here, use indexes to create a multidimensional storage variable.
   end
end
```

So in the end you just have to assign a row in C1 using an index.

Comment: I got this error : The following error occurred converting from cell to double:Error using double, Conversion to double from cell is not possible