# Sorting multi rows from a file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, row, cell

I have a file with various total number of columns as below :

```
1.000000 - 1.000200 0 -> 2 A-MPDU 1.000000 - 1.000100 SUCCESS 1.000100 - 1.000200 FAIL
1.000225 - 1.000270 2 -> 0 ACK SUCCESS [01]
1.000150 - 1.000350 1 -> 3 A-MPDU 1.000150 - 1.000250 FAIL 1.000250 - 1.000350 FAIL
1.000425 1 TIMEOUT
1.000270 - 1.000570 0 BACKOFF
```

I want to sort these rows based on columns4 for row1, 2, 3, 5 and column2 for row4 (in other words, based on column2 or column4) thus it should be like this after sorting :

```
1.000000 - 1.000200 0 -> 2 A-MPDU 1.000000 - 1.000100 SUCCESS 1.000100 - 1.000200 FAIL
1.000270 - 1.000570 0 BACKOFF
1.000150 - 1.000350 1 -> 3 A-MPDU 1.000150 - 1.000250 FAIL 1.000250 - 1.000350 FAIL
1.000425 1 TIMEOUT
1.000225 - 1.000270 2 -> 0 ACK SUCCESS [01]
```

How to realize this output? Should I count total number of column for each row first to decide whether I use column2 or column4?

Comment: You already asked how to read in the file:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825221/store-same-length-content-to-one-variable-in-matlab there is no need to address this again in this question. I would suggest to add the parsed data to the question and add/link the code you are using to read the file.

Comment: When the number in the 4th\2nd column is the same, how do you decide which should go first?

Comment: If possible, consider changing the format of the file to something that can be easily parsed (like XML or Json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your data has a well-known structure. The *easiest to understand* (but not necessarily cleanest) thing I could think of is as follows:

1. Read the text as one long string:

   `A = [...
   '1.000000 - 1.000200 0 -> 2 A-MPDU 1.000000 - 1.000100 SUCCESS 1.000100 - 1.000200 FAIL'...
   char (10) '1.000225 - 1.000270 2 -> 0 ACK SUCCESS [01]'...
   char (10) '1.000150 - 1.000350 1 -> 3 A-MPDU 1.000150 - 1.000250 FAIL 1.000250 - 1.000350 FAIL'...
   char (10) '1.000425 1 TIMEOUT'...
   char (10) '1.000270 - 1.000570 0 BACKOFF'...
   ];`

   Note: `char(10)` is a line break `\n`. You should get this automatically if reading from a text file.
2. Split the long string into separate cells by using: `B=(strsplit(A,char(10)))';`
3. Use `C = cellfun(@strsplit,B,repmat({' '},size(B)),'UniformOutput',0);` to convert it into a cell array (some rows will contain empty cells at the end because the initial string has less spaces).
4. Convert the 1D array of 1D cell arrays into a single 2D array by:
   `D=C;
   for ind1=1:length(D)
       tmp = length(D{ind1});
       D(ind1,1:tmp)=D{ind1};
   end`
5. Find the rows where the result has a number in the 2nd column:

   `isInd = ~strcmp('-',D(:,2))`
6. Create a list of indices by:
   `idx(ind1,1)=0; %Preallocation
   for ind1=1:ind1 %Extreme variable reuse
       idx(ind1) = str2double(D(ind1,4-2*isInd(ind1)));
   end`
7. Append indices to the array you want to sort and sort according to them:
   `B1 = sortrows([B,num2cell(idx)],2); 
   B_Sorted = B1(:,1);`

The result, with this code, is a sorted cell array.

---

P.S. Anybody who is willing to optimize this code is more than welcome to edit the answer :)

Comment: Thanks you, it was explained well